# TT c-> c# Ho to handle typedef enums

Tags: c#, c, templates

Problem: Interface between C and C#, both should use same enum values. Manual conversion can make problems if something is changing.

Therfeore we try to use tt templates for conversation.

Problem: I don't know how to convert typedef enums in tt.

```
 typedef enum{
    val1=0,
    val2,
 }enumName_eTypeDef;
```

With enums I just copy line by line.

```
if (def.StartsWith("enum"))
    {
 #>
        public <#=def#>
  <#
        while (defines.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            string def1 = defines.ReadLine();

            def1 = def1.Trim();
  #>
            <#=def1#>
  <#
            if(def1.StartsWith("};"))
            {
  #>
  <#
            break;
            }
        }
    }
```

But how would i do this with an typedef enum to get the "enumName_eTypeDef" ?

Comment: What is "tt templates"?

Comment: T4 text templates, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For the interface between the two, I expect that only a limited number of enums will be needed so you can replace those with `#define`s in C and the equivalent in C#. Then you are assured they are the same.